# Cycle through text with overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, cycle

I am trying to cycle through single words that will fade in/fade out and can get this working, although I would like to make it so there is a slight overlap between words before the first one completely disappears.

```js
var divs = $('div[id^="title-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;

(function cycle() {
  divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800).delay(600).fadeOut(700, cycle);
  i = ++i % divs.length;
})();
```

```css
#title-1,
#title-2,
#title-3 {
  font-size: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title-1">Bam</div>
<div id="title-2">Bang</div>
<div id="title-3">Blah</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2020_RG/8fhqbcw5/

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'slight overlap'? In terms of position on screen, or in terms of timing, or something else entirely?

Comment: Also note that Java and Javascript are two ***very*** different things. Java is to Javascript as Ham is to Hamster.

Comment: thanks Rory, yes a slight overlap in terms of timing. The second word fades in slightly before the previous word fades out, creating a slight overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the text effect overlap between words you can use `setTimeout()` to display the next word slightly ahead of displaying the next. You cannot achieve this with the `fadeOut()` callback as that only fires when the previous animation has completed.

To make this work, define a timeout which will run slightly *before* all actions queued on the element complete. In the example below I user a 300ms overlap, but this can be amended as you require.

Also note that for the words to occupy the same space in the DOM their CSS `position` would need to be set to `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky`.

```js
var divs = $('div[id^="title-"]'),
  i = 0;

(function cycle() {
  divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800).delay(600).fadeOut(700);
  i = ++i % divs.length;
  setTimeout(cycle, 1800);
})();
```

```css
#title-1,
#title-2,
#title-3 {
  font-size: 10vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title-1">Bam</div>
<div id="title-2">Bang</div>
<div id="title-3">Blah</div>
```